# How can I create a custom landing page for a specific taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

How would I be able to have a customisable page where in it will be a landing page for special taxonomy terms and will display the related articles of a specific taxonomy term.

For instance, `mywebsite.com/myspecialtaxonomyterm` will display a PAGE, wherein a list of articles related to the tag **myspecialtaxonomyterm** is displayed, beside it is a custom widget as the sidebar and on top of it is a custom block which may contain videos or banner image. Can this be done by the Views module alone or should I create a module for this to be done?

NOTE: This page will be set to be the landing page of a specific tag, based on my example above. I am really confused on how to approach this.

Comment: Have a look at my answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212569/how-to-show-content-type-with-only-related-taxonomy-item

Answer (score 0):

To display only node content with a specific taxonomy term checked, add `Content: Has taxonomy term` to the Filter Criteria of your view. Once you add the filter, you will be prompted to select your taxonomy term vocabulary as well as the term you wish to filter your view by. Once completed, you will only see content associated with the desired term.

If you're using Panels, as your post's tags indicate, you can create your landing page using Pages (comes with panels). Make sure the view you create is a block, not a page, and it will be easy to plug into any panel.