# How to show content type with only related taxonomy item?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a menu that is taxonomy like so:

1. A
2. subterm(A1)##
3. subterm(A2)##
4. subterm(A3)##

Suppose A is menu and I linked a taxonomy vocabulary to menu A.

And suppose that on content type X field taxonomy term type is A1.

How to show content type with only related taxonomy item 
like for taxonomy menu subterm (A1) with content type X related to that term?

Comment: Download and install [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) Module and enable the `Taxonomy term` view. [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/os6dd.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/os6dd.png)